¿Cómo saber el código de cada carácter que se escribe en un control input text en JavaScript?
Mi duda es ¿Cómo saber el número de carácter unicóde del carácter que se escribe en un control input type="text"?


function Escribe(){
    alert(document.getElementById("Texto").value);
}
<input type="text" id="Texto" value="" onkeydown="Escribe()" />




Cuando desarrolles, no uses alerts, usa la consola -> console.log(). Es más eficiente que estar mostrando una alerta a cada rato.
Mientras uqe para el problema, podemos capturar en el evento onkeydown, y ejecutar una función que capture la tecla, la convertimos a unicode, y la mostramos.


function obtenerUnicode(event) {
    const char = event.key; //Obtenemos la tecla presionada
    const unicode = char.charCodeAt(0); //Convertimos a Unicode
    console.log(`Tecla: ${char}, Código Unicode: ${unicode}`);//Mostramos por consola
}
<input type="text" id="Texto" value="" onkeydown="obtenerUnicode(event)" />



